# How to add DVD drive to VM in XenServer using Python

Tags: python, xen

I want to add a DVD drive to VM on xenserver using Python. I created a VM using Python and now I want to add the DVD Drive attached to host to be accessible in VM also. So I need to create a VBD for the DVD Drive as well. But I am unable to get which property I need to set in VBD.Record as in attaching disk, I set up the VDI property and it got attached. But for the DVD Drive, I am unable to figure out which property I need to set to attach that CD Drive to the XenServer. Do help me regarding this.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written about this on my [blog](http://learnwithrahul.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-attach-dvd-drive-to-vm-using.html):

> ```
> sr=session.xenapi.SR.get_by_name_label("DVD drives")
> record_dvd=session.xenapi.SR.get_record(sr[0])
> VDI_dvd=record_dvd["VDIs"]
> vbdconnectcd={'VDI':VDI_dvd[0],
>                   'VM':VM_ref,
>                   'userdevice':"1",
>                   'mode':"RO",
>                   'type':"cd",
>                   'bootable':True,
>                   'unpluggable':True,
>                   'empty':False,
>                   'other_config':{},
>                   'qos_algorithm_type':'',
>                   'qos_algorithm_params':{}}
> vbdref1=session.xenapi.VBD.create(vbdconnectcd)
> ```
>
> Here, `VM_ref` refers to the `uuid` of newly created VM to which we want
>   to add the DVD Drive. Every physical DVD Drive has its VDI which is
>   stored in its properties and one can get it and pass it as one of the
>   parameters to create a VBD linking DVD Drive with the VM.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you directly with the Python part, but I'll try to give the you the correct command line statements.

Assuming the VM already has a DVD drive, you can just issue these commands

```
xe cd-list
xe vm-cd-insert uuid=... cd-name="xs-tools.iso"
xe vm-cd-eject uuid=...
```

.
.

If your interested in the the vbd stuff, the following commands can get you the uuid of the vbd for the DVD drive:

Start with a single VM.  From XenCenter eject the DVD.  Now connect to the XenServer host on the command line, and run:

```
xe vbd-list vm-uuid=...
```

If the VM has an empty DVD drive it's vdi-uuid will be listed as <not in database>.  This will allow you to pinpoint the uuid of the vbd your after!

For more information, check out this link:

> http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/5.0.0/1.0/en_gb/guest.html

Comment: Actually the problem is that the VM does not have the DVD Drive attached to it. I have to attach the DVD Drive to VM and I needed some way to attach the DVD. Finally I came to know that in the properties of DVD, it has a VDI field and one can use this and provide it to VBD and attach the DVD Drive to VM.

Comment: yes... now everything is working... thank you for your valuable suggestions too..... :)

Answer (score 0):

Add CD Drive to XenServer VM using Java

First you have to Connect with xenserver and get the connection variable.

```
 public VBD makeCDDrive(VM vm) throws Exception    {

    VBD.Record vbdrecord = new VBD.Record();

    vbdrecord.VM = vm;
    vbdrecord.VDI = null;
    vbdrecord.userdevice = "3";
    vbdrecord.mode = Types.VbdMode.RO;
    vbdrecord.type = Types.VbdType.CD;
    vbdrecord.empty = true;

    return VBD.create(connection, vbdrecord);
}
```